# iOS AVPlayer issue

Tags: ios, xcode, avplayer

I am new iOS developer .
I am trying to make the play/pause buttons in the now playing bar (home screen bottom bar) simulate the play/pause buttons in my app .
any help please .

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback
                                       error:nil];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES
                                     error:nil];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
[self.player play];

UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier newTaskId = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
if([player play]){
    newTaskId = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:NULL];

    bgTask = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^(void) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask: bgTask];
        bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    }];

    //Your bg code here

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask: bgTask];
    bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
```

Answer (score 0):

After calling:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
```

in your app delegate you will receive events when the buttons are pressed... handle them like this:

```
-(void)remoteControlReceivedWithEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    switch(event.subtype)
    {
        case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlPause:
            [player pause];
            break;
        case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlPlay:
            [player play];
            break;

    }
}
```

And add other cases for next/prev/etc....